# User form in excel to add information to multiple sheets or workbooks

Tags: vba, excel, userform, worksheet

is it possible to use one user form to input the exact same information into two worksheets?

I am trying to input ticket numbers with different colours. I also would like to include yesterdays date and a staff members name who is dealing with that ticket number and what stage that ticket is in. All from one user form. I can input it in one worksheet but how do I ensure that it inputs this information into both worksheets at the same time ?

Answer (score 0):

You address both the worksheets. I assume that you're talking about 2 different **workbooks**, but what I'm writing is just a generalization of a specific case (in which you work with 1 Workbook on 2 different Sheets)

```
Dim WsOne As Worksheet
Dim WsTwo As Worksheet

Set WsOne = Workbooks("DesiredWorkbookNameHere").Worksheets("DesiredWorksheetNameHere")
Set WsTwo = Workbooks("DesiredWorkbookNameHere").Worksheets("DesiredWorksheetNameHere")
```

Then, when you do stuff with your UserForm you can command it to do your action on both of them. For example:

```
WsOne.Range("A1") = Me.TextBox1
WsTwo.Range("A1") = Me.TextBox1
```